# PHP not getting XML data from URL correctly

Tags: php, xml

Simply put, I'm trying to use PHP to get data from an URL and display a list.

Background: I have an application running on one computer that uses APIs and it's own built-in webserver. (This is not my application.) From any computer on my network I can type in the URL (`http://internal-ip-address:port/api/play/getSequences`) and I get the data I expect displayed in a nice XML format.

I am trying to get the PHP script on my webserver on my home server to pull that info and make a list.

I can call that URL from a curl request or from `get_file_contents` and I get the data but it is not in the XML format as expected and I can not parse it as XML.

Output is

```
[{"Name":"SomeName","FileName":"SomeFile"},
 {"Name":"SomeOtherName","FileName":"SomeOtherFile"}
```

Comment: What is the PHP code that results in the above output?

Comment: It looks like its returning json, not xml. Try using json_decode to parse instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not XML is JSON, so you can save content into a $string and do:

```
$data = json_decode($string, true);
```

Then you can access as:

```
echo $data[0]["Name"]; //SomeName
```

Comment: False, if you don't pass second argument in json_decode function you can't access as array but as an object

Comment: Ah ok.  That gets me my array I wanted in the first place.  Thank you!  I haven't done anything with JavaScript or JSON, time to read up a bit.